# "liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax" when there is no error in the SQL

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, liquibase

I am running unit tests on IntelliJ IDEA, using liquibase and h2. The database is entirely created using a SQL script.

The SQL file I'm using looks like this :

```
-- db.table1 definition

CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id   bigint PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
);


-- db.table2 definition

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    id          bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name        varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    description varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    heading     varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


-- db.table3 definition

CREATE TABLE table3
(
    id   bigint       NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Same thing for all of the 77 other tables. The types used are always bigint, varchar, int, date, double, bit, smallint, timestamp. There is nothing else than tables definition and some constraints in the end in this file.

When I start any test, I got the following error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:config/liquibase-test/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.sql::raw::includeAll:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE table2
    (
    id          bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    n' at line 12 [Failed SQL:-- db.table1 definition
```

I verified, the entire SQL file is valid. One of my coworkers have the same file and he does not have a SQL error when starting a test.

If you have any idea or solutions, please share them. (For all the others, have a nice day)